# how to add image for coverflow in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, coverflow

I want to pass the data from 1 view to another in storyboard ..
but it shows error.object at index null or nib is failed to load.
kindly help me... in my first view i have butttontext  view value should be load when i click the button,in the second view 1 image and any body help me

```
 (IBAction)img1:(id)sender 
 {
     SecondViewController *svc =[self.storyboard    
     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
     [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
     [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: Start by reading the "Coordinating Efforts Between View Controllers" section of Apple's View Controller Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW1

Comment: Con you be, bit clear about what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

if your nib file load error. check your storyboard Id

[image]